# Access TextBox value in Gridview when OnTextChanged event triggered from another textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am adding filters to a gridview.  One of the columns is a date field and I have 2 textboxes so the user can enter a range.  After the user enters the second date, the Event is triggered.

However, I can't access the data in the first text box.  I get an error that the object has not been set.

This is the markup:

```
asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open Date" SortExpression="RegistrationOpen">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbOpenDate" Text="Open Date" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="OpenDate"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart" CssClass="datepick"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOpenDateFilter" Text="To"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxOpenDateFilterEnd" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtBoxFilter_TextChanged" CssClass="datepick"></asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
```

This is the OnTextChanged Event:

```
protected void txtBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sender is TextBox)
            {
                populateSectionGrid();
                DataTable dtSectionGridData = SectionGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
                Nullable<DateTime> tdtStartDate;
                Nullable<DateTime> tdtEndDate;

                if (dtSectionGridData != null)
                {
                    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;


                    if (txtBox.ID.Equals("txtBoxOpenDateFilterEnd"))
                    {
                        SectionGridViewFilterExpression = string.Empty;
                        //Get the start date
                        string tstrStartDate = (SectionGridView.FindControl("txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart") as TextBox).Text; \\This is the problem. This Control is returned as not set even though there is a date in the text box.
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tstrStartDate))
                        {
                            tdtStartDate = setStartTime(tstrStartDate);
                            tstrStartDate = "RegistrationOpen >= #" + tdtStartDate + "#";
                        }

                        //Get the end date     
                        string tstrEndDate = string.Empty;
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text))
                        {
                            tdtEndDate = setStartTime(txtBox.Text);
                            tstrEndDate = "RegistrationOpen <= #" + tdtEndDate + "#";
                        }

                        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tstrEndDate))
                        {
                            SectionGridViewFilterExpression = tstrStartDate;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SectionGridViewFilterExpression = tstrStartDate +  " AND " + tstrEndDate;
                        }                       
                    }

                    DataRow[] drFound = dtSectionGridData.Select(SectionGridViewFilterExpression);
                    dtSectionGridData = drFound.CopyToDataTable();
                    SectionGridView.DataSource = dtSectionGridData;
                    SectionGridView.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

How can I access the first text box ("txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart") when the Event is triggered by the text box ("txtBoxOpenDateFilterEnd")?

**UPDATE**
I found some code that has the same functionality that I need using 2 textboxes.
I changed the markup so that only the 2nd text box triggers the event and the function they use to get the data from the first text box uses:

```
(GridView.HeaderRow.FindControl("controlID") as TextBox).Text
```

However, when I use this function, the text box is blank.  I entered a date but when I read it, the text box is empty.
What am I doing wrong?
This is my markup for this header column:

```
 <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbOpenDate" Text="Reg. Open Date" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="OpenDate"></asp:LinkButton>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="datepick"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOpenDateFilter" Text="To"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxOpenDateFilterEnd" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtBoxFilter_TextChanged" CssClass="datepick"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
```

This is the method call having to do with this column:

```
 protected void txtBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sender is TextBox)
            {
                populateSectionGrid();
                DataTable dtSectionGridData = SectionGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
                Nullable<DateTime> tdtStartDate;
                Nullable<DateTime> tdtEndDate;

                if (dtSectionGridData != null)
                {
                    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
else if (txtBox.ID.Equals("txtBoxOpenDateFilterEnd"))
                    {
                        SectionGridViewFilterExpression = string.Empty;
                        //Get the start date
                        string temp = (SectionGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[4].FindControl("txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart") as TextBox).Text;
                        string tstrStartDate = (SectionGridView.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtBoxOpenDateFilterStart") as TextBox).Text;
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tstrStartDate))
                        {
                            tdtStartDate = setStartTime(tstrStartDate);
                            tstrStartDate = "RegistrationOpen >= #" + tdtStartDate + "#";
                        }

                        //Get the end date     
                        string tstrEndDate = string.Empty;
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text))
                        {
                            tdtEndDate = setStartTime(txtBox.Text);
                            tstrEndDate = "RegistrationOpen <= #" + tdtEndDate + "#";
                        }

                        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tstrEndDate))
                        {
                            SectionGridViewFilterExpression = tstrStartDate;
                        }
                        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tstrStartDate))
                        {
                            SectionGridViewFilterExpression = tstrEndDate;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SectionGridViewFilterExpression = tstrStartDate + " AND " + tstrEndDate;
                        }                       
                    }

                    DataRow[] drFound = dtSectionGridData.Select(SectionGridViewFilterExpression);
                    dtSectionGridData = drFound.CopyToDataTable();
                    SectionGridView.DataSource = dtSectionGridData;
                    SectionGridView.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out way the event was not getting the date value from the TextBox.
The `SortExpression` in the `TemplateField` had to be removed.
Previous it looked like this:

```
sp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open Date" SortExpression="RegistrationOpen">
```

The corrected version looks like this:

```
sp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open Date">
```

I don't know why the `SortExpression` would affect the filter expression. But removing this attribute allowed the Textbox to be set.